# Screen Capture tool that allows me to use keyboard?

Tags: screen-capture

There are many screen capture tools, but every tool I've tried expects from its user to **click** and then **drag** the area to capture.

Is there a tool that allows me to use the keyboard for both operations, such that I can do precise captures in a relaxed manner - without holding anything? I do not want to capture just windows, but any rectangular region.

Example of usage:

- press hotkey to enter capture mode
- move cursor (cross, loupe, whatever) around using mouse/pad **and** keyboard.
- when I find a good starting place (top-left corner), click or press some key to enter marking state
- now, move cursor to other corner (bottom-right) of the area I want to capture, but without holding anything! Just move cursor with the mouse or using the keyboard, as before.
- when I find a good spot, click again or press some key to finalize capturing.

There is one such tool on Windows that worked this way: *FastStone Capture*

For me this is an essential feature. I simply want to have precision, without holding any buttons or keys.

Comment: Do you mean for example. Holding CRT+CMD Keys down to anchor one corner of a box and using the arrows keys to expand the sides of it's frame. Then another keys combinations to move the capture box around

Comment: Ive edited my post with an example that should answer your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just found that new [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) ($50) does what I need - you still need to drag a rectangle, but then you are allowed to modified it and being able to release a mouse ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only one I know of is [Snapz Pro](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/), but there are a lot of screenshot utilities available for the Mac.

Comment: Thats true - Snapz Pro allows to use keyboard. However, its not that friendly - loupe is controlled by mouse and rectangular may be controlled by keys. I will wait if someone can come with some better software, until I mark this as an answer.

Comment: One more issue: if I lock my mac when SnapzPro is active, it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

You can press command-shift-4 and use space bar to select one of your open windows to capture.

There is a good tutorial on [this page](http://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Screenshot-in-Mac-OS-X).

Comment: I do not want just to capture windows, but **any** region.